# Por que não é interessante uma pessoa sugerir mais de uma possível duplicata para uma mesma pergunta?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, perguntas-duplicadas

Usuários medalha de tag de ouro podem adicionar quantas duplicatas acharem necessário, isso é um privilégio, mas penso que um usuário normal poderia ao menos sugerir 2 ou 3 "indicações" de duplicata para uma mesma pergunta.

O motivo é que tem perguntas que só seriam definitivamente duplicatas com complementos, não me recordo de nenhuma, mas irei postar aqui assim que possível.

Existe alguma implicação técnica, ou motivação para evitar algum tipo de problema no uso de algo assim?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que a implementação do martelo de ouro é diferente da sugestão por fechamento. Eu não ficaria surpreso se descobrisse que o voto para fechar tem um relacionamento 1:1 com duplicata alvo na base de dados.

Comment: @Renan se duas pessoas diferentes sugerem duplicatas diferentes, quando o fechamento é concluído "como duplicata", ambas irão aparecer. Não é algo exclusivo do martelo de ouro.

Comment: Eu entendo... O que eu acho que acontece é que um voto comum deve estar atrelado a uma pergunta alvo, então seríamos capazes de ver até cinco perguntas no motivo do fechamento se cada usuário escolher uma diferente. Já quem tem martelo pode escolher quantas quiser, da forma que quiser.

Comment: [Mesma pergunta no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385/208518).